# Process noisy image to get clean polygons

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I am implementing image segmentation task and the output has a significant noise. I want to process the output image by removing all the noise and keep only the rectangle boxes (or polygons).
**Can someone please suggest good image processing techniques for this?**

For instance, the images which we need to process looks like following:

[image: image which needs to be processed]

and the desired output should be something like following:

[image: desired image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try these techniques probably it work on your problem.

[4 Image Segmentation Techniques in OpenCV Python](https://machinelearningknowledge.ai/image-segmentation-in-python-opencv/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this blog! The Otsu thresholding is giving very good results.